# Error that SQL Login already exists

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I have created 2 SQL Server Database Projects in VS 2013 and imported schemas from 2 databases that reside on the same SQL instance.  Both databases have SQL Users, let's say [MyUser1] and [MyUser2], that use a single SQL Login, let's say [MyLogin].  The issue is both projects want to create the SQL Login and this causes the error

> "SQL71508 The model already has an element that has the same name MyLogin"

**DB1 Project**

`CREATE LOGIN [MyLogin] WITH PASSWORD = N'xyz';`

`CREATE USER [MyUser1] FOR LOGIN [MyLogin];`

**DB2 Project**

`CREATE LOGIN [MyLogin] WITH PASSWORD = N'xyz';`

`CREATE USER [MyUser2] FOR LOGIN [MyLogin];`

I've tried:

1. Removing CREATE LOGIN from one of the projects.  Issue is then CREATE USER generates an error because it wants the CREATE LOGIN for the Login to exist.
2. To find a way to ignore the error, but all I've found is how to ignore warnings.
3. Using the following to check if Login already exists, however an error is generated at the "If" indicating, "SQL700001 The statement is not recognized in this context".

   `If Not Exists (Select name From master.sys.server_principals Where name = 'MyLogin') 
   Begin
   CREATE LOGIN [MyLogin]
   WITH PASSWORD = N'xyz';
   End`

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to correct or work around this issue?  Thanks!

Also, my primary reason for creating the DB2 project was due to views in DB1 that are based on tables in DB2.  Without the DB2 project referenced in the DB1 project, the SQL to create the views generated errors about not finding the tables in DB2. So, if anyone has any thoughts on how to workaround this issue, that would be helpful too.

Comment: You could just remove the logins from the projects, set your schema compare options to ignore them so they don't come back, and handle creating them yourself in a post-deployment script.

Comment: You could also create a separate project, put the login and users in that and add a database "self" reference from each of the other projects.

Comment: Ed Elliot is Correct. Never add the same item twice in SSDT projects.  Where the same item exists in more than one project, create a master project for the server.  Leave the users alone, just move the logins to a common project. Think inheritance when designing SSDT projects.  Do not forget to include the IncludeCompositeObjects switch for deployments of each individual database.

Comment: @stuartd If I remove the SQL for creating MyLogin and MyUser1 from the DB1 project, the project then errors due to permissioning that is done for MyUser1 in other parts of the project.

Comment: @EdElliot - Thank you Ed.  I implemented your suggestion of using a separate project, as encouraged by HeX too, and then self-reference also, however I only put the Login in this project as HeX suggested and left the Users in the DB1 and DB2 projects.  This makes identifying who answered my question a bit difficult, but I think I'm going to mark HeX's since I think leaving Users in the other db projects is the better approach. Unless I can mark both as answer. Thank you again though for your help!

Comment: @HeXanon - Thanks HeX! If you will post as the answer I will mark yours as the answer or at least one of the answers.

Comment: No problem, don't worry about points!  Personally I would move them both into the separate project otherwise you have code duplication (bad) but there are more than one ways to skin a cat.

Comment: @EdElliott - Thanks! Well in my situation, I don't think I have a code duplication issue.  MyUser1 is a user in DB1, so it's being created in the DB1 project and MyUser2 is a user in DB2, so it's being created in the DB2 project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never add the same item twice in SSDT projects. Where the same item exists in more than one project, create a master project for the server.

Leave the users alone, just move the logins to a common project.

Think inheritance when designing SSDT projects. Do not forget to include the IncludeCompositeObjects switch for deployments of each individual database.